# How to break long strings in XAML source code?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, code-formatting

Silly question, but a Google/SO search didn't bring me the desired result. I have a very long string like this:

```
<Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
       VerticalOptions="Start" 
       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
```

How can I break up the `Text` attribute on multiple lines to have a better code formatting? Is there an option or not?

If I enter a new line and add some spaces (for indenting), the label also contains the spaces ...

Answer (score 2):

It's funny I've not really thought about this one before but it's a great question! I always just kept word wrap on the editor so I never noticed...

That looks like xamarin? If so you might add that tag since wpf etc would be `<Label Content="blah"/>` format so it confused me at first.

However, in WPF, Silverlight, UWP, etc, you can just do this and skip the measuring of the ContentPresenter to display as a whole line and wrap accordingly when rendered;

```
<Label>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
     sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore 
     magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam 
     et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, 
     no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem 
     ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam 
     nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam 
     erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo 
     dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata 
     sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</Label>
```

Unfortunately I don't use xamarin currently so if it turns out to be different just me know and I'll del this answer but hope it helps.

Comment: You are right - it's Xamarin XAML. Here I used `<Label.Text>Lorem ipsum ...</Label.Text>`. As a result new lines are rendered like in the editor, but the white spaces in the front are included too. So starting from the second line there is an indentation. The same is with `<Label VerticalOptions="...>Lorem ipsum ...</Label>`. So using word wrap in VS seems to be the best option. You can find it under `Tools > Options > Text Editor > XAML > General` and under **Settings** there is the Option *Word wrap*.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has nothing to do with Xamarin. I use WPF and I had the same problem.

The problem does not only occur in a `Label`, it is in all `Controls`. Every `Control` has a `Text` property.

The cause is that you use the Text property to assign your text, using `Text="..."`

The solution, as [Chris W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090206/chris-w) suggested (maybe without realizing it), is to move the assignment of the Text property to the part between the opening tag and the closing tag; so to the part between `<...>` and `</...>`

So Instead of

```
<TextBox Height="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap"
         Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur ... (etc.)"/>
```

Use:

```
<TextBox Height="auto" TextWrapping="Wrap">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
    ...  (etc.)
<TextBox>
```

Even the spaces / tabs in front of the text will be replaced by one space.

Note that if you use property assignment, you use string quotes: `Text="..."`;
If you use the part between opening and closing tag, there are no string quotes.
That might be the reason that you can add line breaks in your source code.